# Bug reproduction step tracking software

Tags: windows-7, workflow

I'm looking for some form of software which will help me track the **steps to reproduce a bug**.  For example, if I have three buttons, I want to be able to record that pressing `Red -> Green -> Red` will cause a crash, `Red -> Green -> Blue -> Red` will cause a crash, but `Red -> Red` produces the expected behavior.

This doesn't have to be *specifically* for reproducing bugs - anything which will let me easily record a series of repeated actions and a result of those actions is sufficient.

Also, please note I am **not looking for bug tracking software**, which is (unfortunately) all that comes up on Google when searching for this.

---

Specific requirements:

- Ability to enter a series of actions and a result.
- Ability to branch a series of actions and continue following a different path, or report a different result.

  - Alternatively, the ability to clone a series, AND the ability to sort/group them by actions
- Reasonably intuitive UI.
- Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008

Optional:

- Ability to analyze the results and find relationships (such as `Any Red after a Green crashes`)
- Ability to guess what the next step of an entered sequence will be, based on previous steps and auto-branch if different (i.e. "I've seen this before, last time it crashed. It worked this time? New branch")

---

I know that I could do this myself in a text editor or spreadsheet, but I'm looking for something that will make the process easy.

Comment: Is your application a web application? If not, what UI framework does it use?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - It's at least partially a physical device with buttons I need to push by hand.  I can't automate it, unfortunately.  The other part is a pair of .NET apps that interact with the physical device, only one of which I have any control over.